# How to draw a black line down the center of a column, over an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to be able to draw a single black line exactly down the center of a specific column (td). This column contains an image and so the black line would have to be over the top of the image.

I'm attempting this in CSS, but javascript would be OK. I would prefer not to use an image for the black line.

I've attempted:

```
.verticalLine {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

and then:

```
<td align="center" valign="center">
    <div class="verticalLine" id="verticalLine"></div>
etc.
```

...but that doesn't show anything.

I also tried `left: 50%;` and `left: 428;` but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put a image where contain your design ?

Comment: could you use html canvas to draw the line? why don't you put the line on the image itself?

Comment: The image is dynamic and I don't want to waste processing by modifying it on the server even more. Better to do it this way. I don't know about html canvas, please share the code if you have any.

Comment: Are the images fixed width? Also, there's no such thing as `float:center`.

Comment: Yes, the images are fixed width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code:

```
<td align="center" valign="center"><div class="verticalLine" id="verticalLine"></div>
```

The CSS I'd use for this might go as follows:

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
.verticalLine{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

With the TD positioned relative, your line can be positioned `absolute`, which takes it out of the standard flow and won't affect the positioning of other elements in the cell. Of course, it would be better if you applied the `position: relative` to the TD using a class, so it doesn't affect all the other TD tags.

Answer (score 1):

your td needs position relative, then you can position your div relative with 50% and put the border on the left:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

.verticalLine {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;    
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

example here (just used a div with id #wrapper for illustrion-purposes instead of td): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DBphv

Comment: use firebug/chrome inspector to see where this css is overwritten, it should work. i upddated the codepen to work with a table...

Comment: Your code appears to put the black line behind the image, which I think it the same problem I was having.

Comment: i updated codepen to use an image, see the css (including img-css)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="center"><div class="verticalLine" id="verticalLine"></div><img src="http://www.ehdwalls.com/plog-content/thumbs/1440x900/animals/small/610-citten_1440x900.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.verticalLine {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}

td {
     height: 50px;   
}
```

I have made a quick jsfiddle example:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hEqZ5/1/)